# How to modify such data in JS arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

Got issue
My javascript array contains dates
for ex. `19.4.2003,28.11.1997,3.1,,29.6,7.11.2008` (date-month-year).
As you can see some of dates are missing ( just `,,` ) and some are without a year (for ex. `29.6`).
The array above should looks like: `19.4,28.11,3.1,,29.6,7.11`
Then I need to find an element and get its index with `jQuery.inArray("searchVar", myArr);`
The code is below

```
if (data.response) { //response from social network
    var f_cnt = data.response.length;
    for(var i=0;i<f_cnt;i++) { 
        holidaysArr.push(data.response[i].bdate); //pushing date in array
        //modify in loop? or call function to modify later?
    }
    holidaysLoaded=true; // just flag
}
```

Pushing (ok) -> modifying -> searching for element.
Need your help.

*UPDATE*
While making project understand I need to call social network API more than once so saved data in my array. Check it:

```
    if (data.response) {
    friends_data = data.response.sort(sFirstName); //sorting nvm
    f_cnt = data.response.length; //count of arrayfields
    holidaysLoaded=true;    //flag
}
```

So array has `uid`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `bdate` atm. Not just `bdate` as hour ago.
Question is: How to modify all `friends_data[i].bdate` with `match`? Empty birthdays have `undefined` atm. I think I need something like

```
for(var i=0;i<f_cnt;i++){
   friends_data[i].bdate = cutFunc(friends_data[i].bdate);
}
```

and form `cutFunc(param)` with checking on `undefined`, if not it will match with your function?

*UPDATE 2* cutFunc should be smth like this:

```
function cutFunc(param) {
if(param==undefined) return
else return param.match(/\d+\.\d+/g);
}
```

thank you :)

Comment: Hi, if you're using my solution you just have to change `holidaysArr.push(data.response[i].bdate);` to `holidaysArr.push(cutFunc(data.response[i].bdate));`.   Also, I would `return "";` from the cutFunc if `param==undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets a holiday array with just days.month

```
if (data.response) { //response from social network
    var f_cnt = data.response.length;
    for(var i=0;i<f_cnt;i++) { 
        holidaysArr.push(data.response[i].bdate); //pushing date in array
        //modify in loop? or call function to modify later?
    }
          holidaysArr = (holidasArr.join(',')).match(/\d+\.\d+/g);
    holidaysLoaded=true; // just flag
}
```

---

**EDIT** Sorry the regex was wrong; it's been modified with correct regex

---

**EDIT** Here's a [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/skyrim/yezXM/2/)

---

**EDIT** Updated the [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/skyrim/yezXM/2/)

Comment: np...the jsfiddle link I had didn't initially have sample .year data in it, but the new one does (both links point to the new one, now)

Comment: @966p -- also, please mark as solved when you get the chance :)

Comment: I updated the structure, check the *UPDATE* in the mainpost please :s